# Append a row to a CSV from object arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, append

I'm trying to create a script that retrieves data from an API every week and appends the values to a new row in a CSV file. How do I append all the values to a new row in the CSV file.

Section 1 creates an object with two arrays  (1) Column Name  (2) An API query that will run later in the script

```
$QUERY = @()

$QUERY += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ColumnName="HOME"; Value='API QUERY TO RETRIEVE A VALUE'}
$QUERY += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ColumnName="ADMIN"; Value='API QUERY TO RETRIEVE A VALUE'}
$QUERY += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ColumnName="CUSTOM"; Value='API QUERY TO RETRIEVE A VALUE'}
#... There will be approx 30 more lines similar to the above
```

This second section runs the API query and retrieves a value.

```
foreach ( $_ in $QUERY )
    {
        $_.Query= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $_.Query | select -expand results
    }
```

How do I append all the $QUERY arrays in to a new row in the CSV file. I would like the $Query.Value to be placed in the appropriate position based on the $QUERY.ColumnName to prevent the wrong figure being placed in the wrong column.

Here is an example of my CSV

```
HOME,ADMIN,CUSTOM;      #ColumnName
12345,67891,76543;      #Existing Values e.g Week 1
34556;35453,86567;      #Existing Values e.g Week 2
25345,75391,86243;      #I want to append a new row
```

I've been playing around with this for a while and not having much luck! Any guidance will be much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: What is the output of your `Invoke-RestMethod`? I'd like to know how HOME, ADMIN, and CUSTOM can be retrieved.

Comment: It is values similar to those in the CSV e.g HOME = 12345, ADMIN = 67891, CUSTOM = 76543.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When handling CSV files PowerShell maps the fields of a data row to the properties of a custom object and vice versa. For appending a new row to a given CSV you need to create a custom object with properties matching the column names of the CSV and then append that to the CSV.

```
$queryA = 'API query A'
$queryB = 'API query B'
$queryC = 'API query C'

New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    'HOME'   = Invoke-RestMethod ... -Body $queryA
    'ADMIN'  = Invoke-RestMethod ... -Body $queryB
    'CUSTOM' = Invoke-RestMethod ... -Body $queryC
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType -Append
```